# input element NEEDS CSS max-width: 100% or it will default to MORE than 100%

Tags: html, css, input, width

An entirely unstyled text `input` in Chrome defaults to around 177px. OK. But wrap it in a `div` and use CSS to limit the `div` to width, say, 100px, and the `input` breaks out the side o_O. Surprisingly, in Chrome at least, CSS is **needed** to tell `input` it has a max-width, or it will rather impolitely bust out.

```html
<div style="max-width: 100px;"><!-- that CSS FAILS to stop input bustin' out all over -->
    <input name="abc" id="abc" type="text">
</div>

<div style="max-width: 100px;">
    <input style="max-width: 100%;" name="abc" id="abc" type="text"><!-- You need this too... -->
</div>
```

I am surprised by this and can't find any ref to it, so posting here in the hope I learn something.

Of course this is instantly fix-able with CSS, but unlike other unstyled elements, it appears to insist on a default width, regardless of it being *contained* by a narrower fixed-width container.

Comment: The default width of an input element will of course depend on its type. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input which touches on the width aspect. For example, for a type of text (the default type) the width defaults to 20em,

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @AHaworth; I totally missed that buried in there. I am still *slightly* surprised that a text input inside a 10em `div` overflows, yet give it CSS max-width: 100% and it doesn't. I would have assumed the container would have contained the width "aspirations" of the `input` equally as well as that CSS rule. Perhaps I am missing something basic here. But anyway; just great to see an MDN  page noting that innate width. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of default width of `177px` (as you mentioned), it has overflow and you only can see it for example like this:

```html
<div style="max-width: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
  <input name="abc" id="abc" type="text">
</div>
  
<div style="max-width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
  <input name="abc" id="abc" type="text">
</div>

<div style="max-width: 100px;">
  <input style="max-width: 100%;" name="abc" id="abc" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can use CSS. I was just surprised to find an HTML element even *had* a default width, and that it broke out of a container unless you tell it not to exceed 100% width.

I can see the browser makers might well *want* a default width for `input`, but I was surprised not find (yet) that documented and more surprised to find it did not respect the width of its container; unless CSS `max-width: 100%` was applied.